# Hide or uninstall apps for particular users in Mac OSX 10.8

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, uninstall

I am trying to create a second user login on my laptop so I can separate all my personal apps and documents from my work ones as I use my laptop at work. Both accounts have admin privileges.

How can I hide all my personal apps from my work account so they aren't cluttering up my work logins applications folder?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new folder named *Applications* in your home directory. It will automatically use the same icon. This is similar to how there's a system-wide *Library*, and a *Library* containing account-specific settings and files. See Table 1-2 in [this Apple developer document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for reference. Move your personal apps there.